# College wifi works easily on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, wireless-networking

In Linux:

After connecting to the college wifi, going to the network login page logging in, the internet works perfectly as it should.

In Windows:

After connecting to the college wifi, going to the network login page, logging in, Windows shows "Internet access" and the wireless icon turns white. But still after that, regardless of the browser being used, attempting to accessing any page just shows "*Sending request*". It does work though after a lot of tries, but only in intervals.

But when running Ubuntu 11.10 in VirtualBox, it works properly just like booting in Ubuntu, even if it isn't working on Windows.

The college wifi service is really crappy and has been unable to solve this problem. I'm pretty sure there should be a solution for this, but what? What is it that Ubuntu is doing right and Windows isn't?

Windows settings set to "*Automatically detect settings*" and no proxy server used.

tracert in Windows shows(when *not working*)

```
 Unable to resolve target system name google.com.
```

tracert in Windows shows(when *working*):

```
 Tracing route to google.com [74.125.236.70]
 over a maximum of 30 hops:

 1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 2     1 ms     1 ms     4 ms  10.49.0.9
 3     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  1.186.23.17.dvois.com [1.186.23.17]
 4    13 ms    12 ms    12 ms  Static-5.155.93.111.tataidc.co.in [111.93.155.5]
 5    37 ms    36 ms    34 ms  192.168.237.201
 6    33 ms    34 ms    34 ms  72.14.222.166
 7    33 ms    48 ms    60 ms  72.14.232.202
 8    39 ms    39 ms    39 ms  72.14.232.93
 9    39 ms    40 ms    50 ms  209.85.249.235
10    41 ms    39 ms    40 ms  maa03s05-in-f6.1e100.net [74.125.236.70]

Trace complete.
```

traceroute in Ubuntu:

```
  traceroute to google.com (74.125.236.36), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
  1  * * *
  2  * * *
  3  * * *
  4  * * *
  5  * * *
  6  * * *
  7  * * *
  8  * * *
  9  * * *
 10  * * *
 11  * * *
 12  * * *
 13  * * *
 14  * * *
 15  * * *
 16  * * *
 17  * * *
 18  * * *
 19  * * *
 20  * * *
 21  * * *
 22  * * *
 23  * * *
 24  * * *
 25  * * *
 26  * * *
 27  * * *
 28  * * *
 29  * * *
 30  * * *
```

the output of traceroute is varying, sometimes there's some server name on the last line.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which browsers are you using? Some browsers don't like unintended (at least from their point of view) redirection.

Comment: I have used many browsers on both platforms - Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, Opera, IE7/8/9, Rekonq, Konqueror. And for every broswer in Windows, the exact same problem. No problem for any browser in Linux. No problem even in Ubuntu running from a Live CD. I am pretty sure the wifi service differentiates based on OS, so what I'm asking for is, is there a method by which I can fake a Windows session as a Linux session, so the internet will run fine?

Comment: Have you talked to the IT support people in charge of the network?

Comment: Even if I did, that would be useless, horrible customer service. (its a paid network)

Comment: What does `echo $http_proxy` output under ubuntu?

Comment: Shows nothing.
And btw, my new question that was closed is very different from this one. Is there a way to delete this one and reopen the new one again? And how do I PM someone?

Comment: I have updated this question now, please check it out.

Comment: Are other people's Windows machines affected by the same problem?

Comment: If you need to update the background information in your question, editing the question is the preferred way to do that in the Stack Exchange network. Could you please add some information about what hardware and which version of Windows you are using? In particular, I'm curious about your WiFi hardware. Are you using an integrated WiFi (i.e. a laptop where the WiFi is "built-in") or some sort of add-on adapter?

Comment: @user52849 Could you try a `traceroute` on Linux? I still think it's some proxy setting, a `traceroute` (to e.g. `google.com`) would reveal exactly which servers it goes through. And maybe do a `tracert` on Windows to check where the request gets up to before stopping. Please update your question to include the results.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, since the college has provided identical laptops to all students with Windows preinstalled.

Comment: @irrationalJohn
Yes its an Acer laptop with integrated WiFi.
MS Windows 7 32-bit SP1.
Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter.
If more information is needed, I'll post a generated log.

Comment: @Bob I've updated the question. I used "tracert google.com" on Windows and "traceroute google.com" on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Max: have you actually *spoken* to another student with the same problem?  Just because your machines started out identical (or were supposed to) doesn't mean that there isn't a problem with your one.

Comment: Try disabling IPv6 on the network adapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of redirect is usually from the network forcing all users through their proxy servers. It's possible you don't have proxy auto discovery working properly on Windows, see [WPAD on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol). I've had issues with Firefox and WPAD before, finding the correct proxy address and manually setting it worked. Perhaps you can ask your college's IT department for that information (the proxy address)?

Also, make sure this is checked:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCB0g.png)

(Especially if using Internet Explorer, though it also effects other programs that use Windows' proxy settings. Firefox is not affected by this.)

---

Your Ubuntu traceroute shows a whole lot of timing out.. your 'not working' Windows traceroute shows it could not access the DNS server.

Check your DNS server in Ubuntu (`cat /etc/resolv.conf`)

Check your Windows one (`ipconfig /all`)

Are they the same? If not, does it help to make them the same? To set the DNS server(s) in Windows:

1. Type `network connections` in the start menu search. Go to `View Network Connections`.
2. Right click the appropriate adaptor, select `Properties`
3. Select TCP/IP (probably IPv4), click Properties

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j10kv.png)

Comment: I have tried as many browsers as possible on both platforms, and the problem is exactly the same. So I highly doubt that its because of the browser. Also, I ran XP using VirtualBox in Kubuntu, and in that the internet worked perfectly fine, as in Linux.

What I'm basically looking for is, is there a method by which I can fake a Windows session as a Linux session, so the internet will work perfect as it runs in Linux?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no routers that differentiate based on OS. The fact that you can access the login page by navigating directly to the IP probably means either you did not set a proxy correctly (which Linux may have automatically set system wide) or you don't have a DNS server configured properly - try navigating to other sites by IP. The only real difference between Linux and Windows is how their WLAN autoconfiguration works, and since you can navigate directly to the login IP, you are getting onto the network just fine (security settings correct, etc).

Comment: The network might be playing games with DNS.  Linux doesn't cache DNS requests locally, which would explain why it works.  Try running "ipconfig /flushdns" from the command line on your Windows machine and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: I have updated this question now, please check it out.

Comment: @Bob How do I go to TCP/IP properties?

Comment: @Bob Everything set to automatic. And the DNS servers are the same on both Windows and Ubuntu. Posting a screenshot.

Comment: @user52849 Sorry, aside from Harry's tip on caching DNS requests, I have no clue what could be happening. I am assuming the signal strength is somewhat high, at least 4/5 bars - that may make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling IPv6 in connection properties?
I see you have several link-local IPv6 addresses listed as your default gateway and this is a known bug of Internet Connection Sharing. If you disable IPv6, everything should work.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: See @Bob's screen caps. The option is just above Internet Protocol Version 4.

Comment: How to disable it? Sorry didn't quite get it.

Comment: By un-ticking the box that comes before it?

Comment: Oh. -.-
The internet has been working consistently on Windows for an hour now, I'm not sure how. I'll try this for a couple of days then inform. Thank you Bob and billc.cn for your help!

Comment: Even if it continues to work I would suggest considering changing your Windows DNS servers to either [www.OpenDNS.com](http://www.OpenDNS.com) or [Google Public DNS](http://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/). ISP provided DNS is often "less special". (Just my personal opinion/preference.)

Comment: @irrational John that would do him no good as it would prevent him from seeing the login page (which is presented though DNS hijacking). The problem is related to routing or proxy detection, not DNS.